# How to write an Asynchronous Loop using Promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

How do I write a synchronous loop using Promises? Neither of the functions below wait for the previous loop to finish before starting...

```js
(async ()=> {
    let arr = [3,1,2,1,2];

    const waitFor = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

    // Using Promise.all
    const firstFn = async () => { // doens't work
        return Promise.all(arr.map(async (sec) => {
            await waitFor(sec*1000);
            console.log(`waited for ${sec} seconds`);
        }));
    }
    await firstFn();

    // Using new Promise
    const secondFn = async () => {
        arr.map(sec => {
            new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
                await waitFor(sec*1000);
                console.log(`waited for ${sec} seconds`);
                res();
            });
        });
    }
    await Promise.all(secondFn());

})();
```

Comment: There is no `return` in `secondFn ()` and no `return` in either of the `map()`

Comment: Seen as you are using `async / await` use a `for (let sec of arr) {`. Array functions are not async aware..

Comment: You cannot write a promise-based synchronous loop. You can write an asynchronous, sequential loop though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use promise for this. You can use the `for..of` loop for this:

```
for await (const sec of arr){
  await waitFor(sec*1000);
  console.log(`waited for ${sec} seconds`);
}
```

You can learn more about async for of loop here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: Thanks. I was able to write it using a for loop and it works but wondering if there's a way to do it with Promises too?

Comment: Do use a `for … of` loop, not an `for await … of` loop!

Comment: @wongz The code is using promises, `waitFor` does return one

Answer (score 1):

map process the promises in a parallel execution. If you want in sequence use `for... of` , or the simple form of the `for`. Example:

```
async function something () {
  const arr = [3,1,2,1,2];
  for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    const sec = arr[x];
    await waitFor(sec*1000);
    console.log(`waited for ${sec} seconds`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of an asynchronous function that takes a list of asynchronous functions and executes them sequentially. Waiting for one to finish before moving to the other.

```js
const wait =
  ms =>
    new Promise
      ( resolve =>
          setTimeout
            ( () => (console.log(`wait ${ms}`), resolve())
            , ms
            )
      );

const async_chain =
  async ([fn, ...fns]) =>
    typeof fn === 'function'
      ? (await fn(), await async_chain(fns))
      : undefined;

(async function main() {

  await async_chain
    ( [ async () => wait(1000)
      , async () => wait(2000)
      , async () => wait(3000)
      ]
    )

})();
```